# Достать часть строки из ссылки и вставить в часть другой ссылки

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения

есть задача доставать выделенную жирным часть строки https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**8YamFtDEPZU** для видео, которые я буду вставлять в строку для ссылок в Wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтоб потом добавлять эту же часть строки в этот адрес — https://img.youtube.com/vi/**8YamFtDEPZU**/maxresdefault.jpg и получать превью видео с youtube. Очень буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрав URL как пример

```
$link = parse_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DN2oRg9Wx0&as=asdf");
parse_str($link['query'], $link);
echo $link['v'];
```

Или регуляркой(Обновил)

```
preg_match('#(\.be/|/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,11})#', $link, $matches);
$YoutubeCode = (isset($matches[2]) && $matches[2] != '') ? $matches[2] : "";
echo $YoutubeCode;
```

Регуляркой лучше, она будет больше вариантов обрабатывать в то время как разбор URL надо постоянно указывать из какого параметра брать

И к тому же разбор url не покажет ничего если будет типа youtu.be/id